# One Information and other side Picture of the user

Tags: php, html, loops, pdf

I am trying to divide the page like one side there should be Information about the user like name,email,address,mobile and in the front of this i want the image of the user.
You can check the image of the need
[Blue box is image of the user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGMAn.jpg)

here is the loop where this information is fetching

```
$tcpdf = new TCPDF();
$tcpdf->AddPage();
//----->User<-----\\
$tcpdf->SetFont('times', '', 10.5);
$displayed=false;
$useroutput[]='<table>';
foreach($row3 as $key11=>$value11)
{
    $useroutput[]='<tr>';

    $useroutput[]='<td>'.$key11.':'.$value11. '</td>';

    $useroutput[]='</tr>';
}
$useroutput[]='</table>';
$user=join($useroutput);
$tcpdf->writeHTML($user, true, false, false, false, '');
$tcpdf->Output();
```

Comment: So where is the code to place the image? And where is the image that you want placing?

Comment: yes that what i need to know where should i put the image code and how

Comment: help me here guys

Comment: @RiggsFolly Image is in same directory where this code file exist.

Comment: Put it somewhere! See what it looks like!! If its not in the right place, THEN ask for help

Comment: i'd help but i dont know anything about the code you are using, would you like your solution in javascript and html ?

Comment: ok tell me in javascript

Comment: when i am doing with table tag there is gap between id and name

Comment: one there should be well managed and the front of this there should be image like we see in resume

Comment: I solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

heres in html/ css

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
}
#left {
  width: 300px;
      margin-left: 5px;
      
     

}
#right {
  flex: 1;
  border:solid;
}

ul {list-style: none;}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="left"><ul>
<li>Id:</li>
<li>Name:</li>
<li>Address:</li>
<li>Email:</li>
</ul>
</div>


 <div id="right"><img src="https://www.google.org/static/logo_googledotorg.svg"></img></div>
</div>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>quanity</th>
     <th>price</th>
     <th>address</th>
     <th>status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>17500</td>
    <td>@mandi</td>
    <td>fresh</td>
      </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Banana</td>
    <td>3000</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```